# Living out of one another's pockets

Tags: meaning

> Neither Anastasia Alexandrovna nor he felt that they could live another minute out of one another's pockets.

What does this mean? Does it mean they can't live without one another (because they are in love)?

Comment: It is a figure of speech in English.  (Every English speaker knows it.)  BUT the writer is using it in a changed-around way. FWIW, for me it's poorly written and doesn't come off. The trick of "changing around" a figure of speech is difficult to do; it can come off just messy and confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase [*living in each other's pockets*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+in+each+other%27s+pockets) means that they spend too much time together.

It stands to reason that the phrase you've quoted means the opposite.  That they wish to live *in* each other's pockets, not *out* of each other's pockets.

Hence, I believe that your assessment is correct.  They cannot live without one another another minute.

It's a strange turn of the phrase, but it seems accurate.

Comment: +1 - is that a common idiom? I've never heard it.

Comment: @medica Common, no.  But, I've heard it.

Comment: You've really made me think of something here @David.  100% of native English speakers know the phrase "living in each other's pockets".  BUT, as you suggest, it's not commonly used. That's kind of weird - I wonder if there's a word for that!?